# How to add variable into Alloy controller and use it when the user click on the TableView

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I have build a simple view in appcelerator that show a TableView. I have also add EventListener on this table, so if the user click on on row of this table I can expanded this table with other (details) rows.

Now this works, but I'm not able to remove this details rows.

Si this is the code:

```
$.table.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if(e.rowData.ignore){//empty row click
        console.log("Ignored");  
        return;//do nothing
    }
    //RECUPERO LA RIGA CHE HO CLICCATO
    var index = parseInt(e.index);//e callback is String, parse to int

    //VERIFICO SE QUESTA RIGA HA SOTTO RIGHE
    if( map[index] != null){
        //SIGNIFICA CHE QUESTA RIGA HA SOTTO RIGHE
        var newSubRow = Alloy.createController('familyHistory_row_children_header',{
            age:L(lang+"age"),
            diagnosi:L(lang+"diagnosis"),
            date_start:L(lang+"start_date"),
            date_end:L(lang+"end_date")
        }).getView();
        //CREO LA TESTATA DELLA SOTTO TABELLA
        $.table.insertRowAfter(index, newSubRow);
        arrayItems.forEach(function (item, i, array) {
            var subItem = Alloy.createController('familyHistory_row_children',{
                age:item.age,
                diagnosi:item.diagnosi,
                date_start:item.dateStart,
                date_end:item.dateEnd
            }).getView();
            $.table.insertRowAfter(1+index+i, subItem);
        });
    }
});
```

**familyHistory_row_children_header.js**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.age.text = args.age;

$.diagnosi.text = args.diagnosi;

$.date_start.text = args.date_start;

$.date_end.text = args.date_end;
```

**familyHistory_row_children.js**

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

$.age.text = args.age;

$.diagnosi.text = args.diagnosi;

$.date_start.text = args.date_start;

$.date_end.text = args.date_end;
```

I think if it is possible to add other variable in **familyHistory_row_childre_header.js** then when I insert detail rows I can set this parameter = true (for example) and implements in the listener if parameteri=true then remove details rows.

It is possibile to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want, but you can pass events as arguments, or set functions and properties to the top level of the row

index.js

```
$.table.hideRowChildren = function(start,end) {

    //remove or hide the row
};
```

familyHistory_row_childre_header.js

```
$.row.myHeader = false;

$.row.setMyHeader = function(val) {

    $.row.myHeader = val;

    if(val) args.hideRowChildren(args.myFirstChildrenRow,args.myLastChildrenRow);
};
```

When you click on the familyHistory_row_children_header, to show its familyHistory_row_children, you could do this:

```
$.table.addEventListener('click',function(e) {

    e.row.myHeader = true;

    //or

    e.row.setMyHeader(true);
});
```